# import node js modules inside Cypress typescript project

Tags: cypress, mailhog

I want to import a node module and add it to my `command.ts` in cypress. the tutorial suggests adding

```
import 'cypress-mailhog';
```

to the `command.js` file. when I add it to my `command.ts` file, I am not able to use the command for example

```
 cy.mhGetMailsBySubject
```

the error is `TS2339: Property 'mhGetMailsBySubject' does not exist on type 'cy & EventEmitter'.`

the modules I am trying to use is
https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-mailhog

in my tsconfig.json file i have the following, among others

```
"target": "es6", 
"module": "commonjs", 
"lib": ["dom","es6", "es5", "dom.iterable"]
```

How could I use `mhGetMailsBySubject` in my test case

Comment: Did you install the module cypress-mailhog in your project using npm install --dev cypress-mailhog and add the base url of your MailHog installation to your cypress.json? For me,   "mailHogUrl": "http://localhost:8025", worked.